# Having trouble making hidden/visible error message

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom, coldfusion

I am making a contact form, which includes name, email and a message which can then be submitted. If any of the three fields are null an error message is shown which I have working. The word "error" appears in all three field boxes. My issue is that I am trying to add a single error message which will be hidden and only appear if an error is made, this will say "Please fill in all fields before submitting"

I am new to ColdFusion and mixing HTML with JavaScript. So I was wondering if anyone could please give me some tips as to what I have done wrong. I have tried to manipulate it many ways and tried adding a div for this message in my CSS. But to no avail, the message always shows up. It doesn't stay hidden when needed.

I would really appreciate any information or help anyone could give, I am so confused and have searched the whole web looking for this info.

Here is my code:

```
var requiredFields = ["name", "email", "message"];

function checkContactForm() {
    var myForm = document.forms[0];

    for (i in requiredFields) {
        fieldName = requiredFields[i];
        if (!myForm[fieldName].value || myForm[fieldName].value == "Error") {
            myForm[fieldName].style.color = "#f66";
            myForm[fieldName].value = "Error";
            var emptyFields = true;
        }
    }
    if (!emptyFields) {
        myForm.submit();
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById("name == null || email == null || message == null")
            document.getElementById("errormessage").style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("errormessage").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }

    function resetField(myField) {
        if (myField.value == "Error") {
            myField.style.color = "#000";
            myField.value = "";
        }
    }

    function resetForm(myForm) {
        var myForm = document.forms[0];

        for (i in requiredFields) {
            fieldName = requiredFields[i];
            myForm[fieldName].style.color = "#000";
        }
    }
```

and here is the CSS for my error message:

```
#errormessage {
    font-style: italic;
    text-indent: 10px;
    border: dotted;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: `if(document.getElementById("name") == '' || document.getElementById("email") == '' || document.getElementById("message") == '')`

Comment: your if() condition doesn't have an open brace but it has a closing brace.First , make sure that there are no typos

Comment: Thank you i will find my errors now and fix that. Sorry to be a bother

Comment: Okay so i fixed my errors and now it is visible when i open the page  even though it should not be, then when i enter the wrong information it becomes hidden which it shouldn't. Do i need to declare this as hidden in my css sheet?

Comment: Yup.It should be hidden initially

Comment: No Prob . Did it work ?

Comment: Hmmm no :( for some reason it is doing the opposite of what it should. it appears when i open the page, but soon as i submit, then it becomes hidden even if i refresh the page. I am reading my java books trying to understand what i have done wrong

Comment: Can you post the entire code on jsfiddle . I'll see what I can do

Comment: sorry i dont know what j s fiddle is?

Comment: okay.Can you post the entire code here

Comment: i found it and made one here is my link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mila_G/gbJq6/

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do form validation with ColdFusion.  If you use `<cfform>` and `<cfinput>` tags then a lot of JavaScript is written for you.  All you have to do is something like this:

```
<cfform action="whereever">
<cfinput type="text" name="fred" required="yes" message="fred is required">
<input type="submit">
</cfform>
```

It's not as fancy as what you are attempting, but it's simple and it's effective.

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the below code and see what you have done wrong.

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body onload="checkContactForm();">

        <style type="text/css">
            #errormessage  {

                font-style: italic;

                text-indent: 10px;

                border: dotted;

                border-width: 1px;

            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var requiredFields = ["name", "email", "message"];
        function checkContactForm() {

            var myForm = document.forms[0];
            for (i in requiredFields) {

                fieldName = requiredFields[i];
                if (!myForm[fieldName].value || myForm[fieldName].value == "Error") {

                    myForm[fieldName].style.color = "#f66";
                    myForm[fieldName].value = "Error";
                    var emptyFields = true;
                }

            }

            if (!emptyFields) {
                myForm.submit();
            }

            else

            {
                if (emptyFields) {
                    document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML  = "Validation Error";
                    document.getElementById("errormessage").style.visibility = "visible";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("errormessage").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }

            }
        }
        function resetField(myField) {

            if (myField.value == "Error") {

                myField.style.color = "#000";
                myField.value = "";
            }

        }

        function resetForm(myForm) {

            var myForm = document.forms[0];
            for (i in requiredFields) {

                fieldName = requiredFields[i];
                myForm[fieldName].style.color = "#000";
            }

        }

        </script>



        <div id="errormessage"></div>

        <form action="STO1.html" method="POST" name="myForm">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
            <input type="text" name="message" id="message"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```